# How to search for string in array?

Tags: php

I have a string in a custom field `usp-custom-60`:

```
Via Prospero Lavarello, 2, 16142 Genova GE, Italia
```

Then I get a value from `GET`

```
$myTerm = $_GET['cityName'];
```

And now `$myterm` is **genova**

And I have a loop where I am first trying to split the whole string and convert it into an array, then I am asking if a term is in array:

```
$catIds = array();

    while  {
        $query->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $custom_field = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-60');
        $custom_field   = explode(" ", $custom_field);
        if (in_array($myTerm, $custom_field, true)) {
            array_push($catIds, $id);
            var_dump($catIds);
    }
```

But I get no results. If I do `var_dump($custom_field)` I get;

```
array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "Via" [1]=> string(8) "Prospero" [2]=> string(10) "Lavarello," [3]=> string(2) "2," [4]=> string(5) "16142" [5]=> string(6) "Genova" [6]=> string(3) "GE," [7]=> string(6) "Italia" } array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "Via" [1]=> string(8) "Prospero" [2]=> string(10) "Lavarello," [3]=> string(2) "2," [4]=> string(5) "16142" [5]=> string(6) "Genova" [6]=> string(3) "GE," [7]=> string(6) "Italia" } array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "Via" [1]=> string(9) "Adalberto" [2]=> string(7) "Catena," [3]=> string(2) "4," [4]=> string(5) "20121" [5]=> string(6) "Milano" [6]=> string(3) "MI," [7]=> string(6) "Italia" }
```

Based on the other answer suggested, I tried the following

```
$myTerm = $_GET['cityName']; 

$catIds = array();

$args = get_posts( 
    array( 
        'post_type'      => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    ) 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $custom_field = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-60');
        if (strpos($custom_field, $myTerm) !== false) {
            array_push($catIds, $id);
        }     
        if(count($catIds) > 0){
            $arrayFUllCity = "fullCity";
        } else {
            $arrayFUllCity = "empty";
        }
    }
    //$catIds = implode( ", ", $catIds );
    var_dump($catIds);
}
```

But I get `array(0) { }` even tho the `echo $custom_field` gives me  3 results with

```
Via Prospero Lavarello, 2, 16142 Genova GE, Italia

Via Prospero Lavarello, 2, 16142 Genova GE, Italia

Via Adalberto Catena, 4, 20121 Milano MI, Italia
```

Comment: I don't entirely follow--can you not use `strpos`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: @ggorlen why strops? I have an entire string, I need to check if $myterm is in string

Comment: @rob.m That's exactly what `strpos` does, check if a string is in a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains a specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word)

Comment: @ggorlen question updated

Comment: @admcfajn question updated

Answer (score 1):

Your issue (as far as I can see is that you have a case mismatch between `$myTerm` which is `"genova"` and the string, which has `"Genova"` in it. Since [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) is case-sensitive, the check fails. I would use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) on the original string to solve this, using `\b` to check for word boundaries around `$myTerm`, and the `i` modifier to make the regex case-insensitive:

```
$custom_fields = 'Via Prospero Lavarello, 2, 16142 Genova GE, Italia';
$myTerm = 'genova';
echo preg_match("/\b$myTerm\b/i", $custom_fields);
```

Output:

```
1 (true)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/dvQ5X)

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of case using `strpos` is best way.
From my end it's not possible to run your code because of database relationship. but you can try this solution. May be problem in extra spacing.

```
$catIds = array();

    while  {
        $query->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();
        $custom_field = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-60');
        $custom_field = explode(" ", $custom_field);
        $custom_field = array_map('trim', $custom_field);
        if (in_array($myTerm, $custom_field, true)) {
            array_push($catIds, $id);
            var_dump($catIds);
    }
```

Comment: I still get `array(0) { }` even tho the strings are as per the bottom of my question

Comment: try to echo $id  to be sure $id is not blank.

Comment: if I place echo $id before in_array, I get 127431 127429 127427 array(0) { }

Comment: this isn't working $custom_field = explode(" ", $custom_field);

Comment: explode should work. check your $custom_field  >> echo $coustom_field; before explode

Comment: I did, and I get `Via Prospero Lavarello, 2, 16142 Genova GE, Italia`

Comment: I have build this based on your given output. working from my end.

https://pastebin.com/Pw6LvY3H

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183990/discussion-between-himel-rana-and-rob-m).